# The peasant atop the world

Tags: chess, humor

Mate in four, White is in glee

But all is not as you see

For it takes a certain trick

A broken rule to break you must pick

Tell me the **one** rule and the grand solution

And points you shall earn with attribution!

[image]

EDIT: I have slight adjusted the diagram due to a mistake. Sorry for the inconvenience!

Comment: There's a checkmate in one I can see there; all you do is stop playing fair. *chucks opponent's king off the board*

Comment: @Avi Problem is that the king will run to his captured army and reside in their protection!

Comment: Oh, guess that won't work then :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> You say "pawn on top" and "mate in four", so maybe White simply captures on f8 without promotion, i.e. the pawn stays a pawn (or promotion to a "top peasant," whichever you prefer, or even to a second white King (?) because "a peasant atop the world" is a ruler(?) Anyway, in both cases the pawn won't promote to a rook or queen, as that would then be an immediate stalemate.
>
>  But more importantly, the pawn promotes neither to bishop or to knight.  Now, that is important. It enables the king to come back to e6 and d6 squares safely and get mated on d6 by the rook. This line is 1. exf8=Pawn! Kf5 2.Rg7 Ke6 3. Ng3 Kd6 4.Rg6#. If the pawn would have been promoted to a knight, then Rg7 causes stalemate, and if the pawn would have been promoted to a bishop then Ng3 causes stalemate, and *without* Rg7 there is no mate in four, so...

Comment: I thought it bears a message that "from the lowest class with hard work -or/and by a clever trick- you can reach to the top and become a ruler. Following this idea there will be a civil war on the table, one part of the White army loyal to the former King, the others make a military coup. The task is to find a certain strategy to restore order among Whites, and obviously in the meanwhile mating black King. If you construct    such a chess puzzle, you'll get my upvote! Xd

Answer (score 4):

Supposing it's white's turn

> Take the bishop in f8 and promote your pawn. Usually, you would promote to Queen: that's not an actual rule *per se*, but why would you take anything else?
>  Well, in that case, promoting to Queen would result in a stalemate... But if you're willing to break this informal "rule" and instead promote to Knight, it's an instant checkmate!